# Mercurial workflow help - how to make a tag of a tag and get it to central repo?

Tags: mercurial

I'm new with HG, I'm looking for some advice on how to handle this scenario.

We have a central repo hosted at Kiln. The three guys on my team code away and eventually are ready with our code which we tag and release as `Version1`.  We then happily start working on our next major version.  While working on it, there's the need to fix a critical bug in `Version1` so James clones his repo using `hg clone -r Version1 http://centralrepo` where he makes his change and tags it as `Version1.1`.

Now, how does Version1.1 get back to the central repo? Using `hg push` causes an abort because there are two remote heads.  Without it being in the central repo, Doug can never come along and make a fix to `Version1.1` if it ever becomes necessary.

How can I modify my process so that all my tags are always stored on the central repo and easily pulled into the dev branch?

**UPDATE/EDIT**

With the suggestion from Joel, I made the following tweaks:

On the Kiln website, I create my main active dev repo. Once I have the code in there, I create a new branch from it.

I clone my ActiveDev branch:  `hg clone http://activeDev code-activeDev` 
I clone my Stable branch: `ht clone http://stable code-stable`

I setup a tag on my stable branch: `hg tag V1.0` and then push it to the stable branch and to the active dev branch. When going to activeDev I use the -f command. Now both branches are identical.

I do an `hg pull` and start on a new feature in ActiveDev. Then push that feature back to central:

`hg com`
`hg push`

Stable gets a bug fix, then pushed to it's own repo using the same two commands. Now when I try to push that fix to the activeDev branch, I'm again given the 'you are making two heads, use -f' message. However, if I force it, the new feature I pushed earlier in `activeDev` is blown away by the fixes I did in `stable`.

Did I do something wrong? Am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: Yeah. You need to read the article I linked. You made 2 clones as branches, rather than having 2 named branches **in the same repo**. You still have not merged. But since you're still new to Mercurial, read [HgInit](http://hginit.com) before the article.

Comment: It seems that using Kiln's "Branch" is not the same as creating a new branch using `hg branch stable` - how do I move changes from stable to activeDev and vice versa?

Comment: To merge between named branches, you `hg update <branch_name>` to the target branch first. Then you do `hg merge <other_branch_name>`. So to get bugfixes from `stable` into the development on `default`, you `hg update default` and then `hg merge stable`.

Comment: Can it go the other way? I.e, can I merge from default into branch as is suggested by the link you provided? When I try `hg update stable` then `hg merge default` it says I can't merge with an ancestor. NVM - I had to hg pull first and then it worked to merge from default to stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to merge the fix so that there is only 1 head again. There is [a way of managing 2 branches](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/05/mercurial-workflows-stable-default/) that makes doing bugfixes on released versions (in parallel with development) easier:

The process I use is to create a named branch called `Stable` in addition to the `default` branch. I work on new features and whatnot on the `default` branch. Whenever I do an actual release of code, I merge that over to the `Stable` branch and only tag things like `v1.0`, `v1.1`, etc. on that branch.

Then I can continue development on the `default` branch, but when a bug comes up that is relevant to a previous version I can put that fix on the `Stable` branch and recompile. When ready, I merge fixes from the `Stable` branch over to `default` to make sure that `Stable` is always just a subset of `default`.

If you start using this, the first time you push that named branch to central you will have to use `hg push --force`, but only once.

Comment: Thanks@Joel. I've been playing around with this - it appears to be a sound idea. Although the part where I do `hg push -f http://default` from my `stable` branch seems to always be required, not just once. Otherwise I get the 'push creates new remote heads' message... I'll edit my question with specifics....

Comment: You probably still have that other head. What does `hg heads` output?